# How do I display a resource property image in <Image>?

Tags: bitmapimage, winui-3, imagesource

I'm trying to display an image I have saved as a resource under the properties category.
This property however returns a `byte[]` which can't be displayed by `<Image>` since it can't convert it to `ImageSource`.
The code looks like this:

```cs
public byte[] MyImage = Properties.ImageResources.MyImage
```

but plugging `MyImage` into

```xml
<Image Source="{x:Bind MyImage}"
```

gives me a conversion error as described above.

I've already tried converting the image to a bitmap to display this instead, but I got the very same error.
I've read alot about something like

```cs
bitmapImage.BeginInit();
bitmapImage.StreamSource = memory;
bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
bitmapImage.EndInit();
```

but then it tells me it can't resolve any of the `BitmapImage` Functions -> BeginInit, EndInit, StreamSource and CacheOption.

I've searched far and wide but they all end in this `BeginInit()` and `EndInit()` function which do not exist for me.

Comment: Is your question about WPF or WinUI3? you should remove one of the tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [the help of EldHasp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74453412/20453719) I've found a way to make the images appear.

I have created a data binding converter class that implements the `IValueConverter` interface:

```cs
public class ByteArrayToBitmapImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object? Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (value is not byte[])
        {
            return null;
        }

        using var ms = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
        using (var writer = new DataWriter(ms.GetOutputStreamAt(0)))
        {
            writer.WriteBytes((byte[])value);
            writer.StoreAsync().GetResults();
        }

        var image = new BitmapImage();
        image.SetSource(ms);
        return image;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language) => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Or shorter:

```cs
public object Convert(
    object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
{
    BitmapImage image = null;

    if (value is byte[] buffer)
    {
        using var ms = new MemoryStream(buffer);
        image = new BitmapImage();
        image.SetSource(ms.AsRandomAccessStream());
    }

    return image;
}
```

It would be used in XAML e.g. like shown below, when `MyImage` is a public property of the object in the DataContext of the Grid:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <local:ByteArrayToBitmapImageConverter x:Key="ImageConverter"/>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <Image Source="{Binding MyImage, Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: @Clemens Would you happen to know why I can't use an `x:Bind` there? it makes the application crash :o

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a UWP application? In WPF, when Binding is used, type conversion is performed. The ImageSource type provides conversion from the Stream, byte[], Uri and string types. You are using x:Bind. And x:Bind does no type conversion.
I'm not sure about UWP, but try replacing x:Bind with Binding.

You can get an ImageSource from an array of bytes like this:

```cs
    BitmapImage bitmap = new();
    using (MemoryStream stream = new(imageBytes))
    {
        bitmap.BeginInit();
        bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        bitmap.StreamSource = stream;
        bitmap.EndInit();
    }
    bitmap.Freeze();
```

Also, keep in mind that bindings require properties, not fields.

```cs
public byte[] MyImage {get;} = Properties.ImageResources.MyImage;
```

For WinUI it might be like this:

```cs
    var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();

    using (var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
    {
        using (var writer = new DataWriter(stream))
        {
            writer.WriteBytes(bytesArray);
            writer.Store().Wait();
            writer.Flush().Wait();
            writer.DetachStream();
        }

        stream.Seek(0);
        bitmapImage.SetSource(stream);
    }
```

I took as a basis the code from the topic: [Convert byte[] to Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42525083/13349759).
The topic shows an asynchronous solution.
Here I tried to upgrade it to synchronous.
I'm not sure if my code is correct because there are many types and methods in WinUI that I don't know about.

Comment: It's a MVVN Winui3 Application so I'm not entirely sure. I've previously used the normal `{Binding MyImage}` but this did result in the very same error aswell.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know WinUI well enough to answer such details.
But the principle of operation of Binding should be the same as in WPF.
Are you sure that the error you have is because of the property type?

I will add to my answer the code for getting a BitmapImage from an array of bytes. But I'm afraid that the error is not related to this.

Comment: As I said I don't have any of these Init() functions. Am I missing some reference?

Comment: I've updated my answer again.